# Recursive generic class declaration without using interface

Tags: c#, generics, recursion

I have following code as object model for the searching, which user is doing on the client side, which works great:

```
public class DemographicAttribute
{
    public string DemographicAttributeValue { get; set; }
}

public class AudienceOperators<T>: IAudienceOperators
{
    public string DemographicAttributeType { get; set; }
    public List<T> Operand { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    //List<U> Entity2 { get; set; }

    public AudienceOperators(List<T> operand, string _operator = null, string demographicAttributeType = "")
    {
        Operand = operand;
        Operator = _operator;
        DemographicAttributeType = demographicAttributeType;
    }
}


public interface IAudienceOperators {}
```

Usage is folowing:

```
DemographicAttribute atr1 = new DemographicAttribute();
atr1.DemographicAttributeType = "Occupation";
atr1.DemographicAttributeValue = "White collar";

DemographicAttribute atr2 = new DemographicAttribute();
atr2.DemographicAttributeType = "Occupation";
atr2.DemographicAttributeValue = "Blue";

DemographicAttribute atr3 = new DemographicAttribute();
atr3.DemographicAttributeType = "Age";
atr3.DemographicAttributeValue = "10 - 14";

DemographicAttribute atr4 = new DemographicAttribute();
atr4.DemographicAttributeType = "Age";
atr4.DemographicAttributeValue = "15 - 25";

AudienceOperators<String> op1 = new AudienceOperators<String>(new List<String> { atr1.DemographicAttributeValue, atr2.DemographicAttributeValue }, "OR", atr1.DemographicAttributeType);
AudienceOperators<String> op2 = new AudienceOperators<String>(new List<String> { atr3.DemographicAttributeValue, atr4.DemographicAttributeValue }, "OR", atr3.DemographicAttributeType);
AudienceOperators<IAudienceOperators> op3 = new AudienceOperators<IAudienceOperators>(new List<IAudienceOperators> { op1, op2 }, "AND");
```

To be able to create instance of the generic class with itself as T I needed to create the blank interface. But I think, its not the best code practice. Is there any other way?

Comment: What do you mean with *I needed to create the blank interface*?

Comment: He wants `Foo<Foo<>>` which isn't possible.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I think OP means the empty interface.

Comment: This looks a bit like the decorator pattern. I would suggest to check it out, maybe it's useful for you.

Comment: thanks for help, the Foo<Foo<object>> did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, use object?

```
AudienceOperators<object> op3 = new AudienceOperators<object>(new List<object> { op1, op2 }, "AND");
```

And you don't have to declare IAudienceOperators.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special to allow a "recursive" generic instance.

```
public class Recursively<T> {
    public T Instance { get; set; }
}

...

var recursively = new Recursively<Recursively<Recursively<string>>>();
Console.WriteLine(recursively.Instance.GetType().ToString());
Console.Writeline(recursively.Instance.Instance.GetType().ToString());
Console.Writeline(recursively.Instance.Instance.Instance.GetType().ToString());
```